# Hive table date column value converson

Tags: hive, hiveql

in Hive table value for one column is like 01/12/17.But I need the value in the format as 12-2017(month-year).How to convert it?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the string to a `unix_timestamp` and output the required format using `from_unixtime`.

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col_name,'MM/dd/yy'),'MM-yyyy')
```